# Should I use OPTION (RECOMPILE) in a query that has several optional parameters

Tags: sql-server

I have a query used in a SSRS report with more than 20 optional filters. These filters generate a bunch of @PARAMETER IS NULL OR COLUMN = @PARAMETER in my query, which is known as a cause of performance problems.

I've heard that OPTION (RECOMPILE) would cause SQL Server to analyze this conditions before generating the execution plan, so my question is: will it be a good option for this kind of query?

Comment: What you are referring to is parameter sniffing, where the stored procedure is ran with the same parameters about 90% of the time, and sql  optimizes for this, and for the other 10% of the time it performs horribly bad. However, it really depends if your query is being ran with the same parameters most of the time, or if you need to look into indexes and rewriting the query rather than forcing SQL Server to not use a cache plan.

Comment: Here is a classic very good article by Erland Sommarskog [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). Yes, you should use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

Comment: It depends: if that stored procedure it isn't executed frequently then RECOMPILE could be a solution. Otherwise, I would use dynamic queries. Read,  Sommarskog's article.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this pattern is that it prevent index usage. Recompiling specialized the query for the exact parameter values being used. That restores  index usage.

If the query run time is far bigger than compile time there really is no problem with recompiling a lot. The costs are insignificant in this case. For a manually executed report 50ms of compile time should not be a problem at all. This is a good use case.